# CSS, JS Mousedown Getting Stuck During Drag Event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on the Etch-a-Sketch project from The Odin Project and I'm trying to make it so that my grid element ('div' in this case) changes color when my cursor is over it and while my mouse is down.

The code I have now works, however, there's an issue with the mousedown portion where it will get intermittently stuck down.  It seems to occur during an accidental drag event. I'll notice a hand drag icon appear on my cursor and then all the other grid elements I mouseover will change color regardless of the mousedown condition.

Is there a way to turn off just the 'draggable' portion of a 'div' or is there another workaround I should be considering?

```
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
grid.addEventListener('mouseover', colorGrid);

let mousedown = false;
grid.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    mousedown = true;
});

grid.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    mousedown = false;
});


function colorGrid(e){
    if(mousedown) e.target.style.backgroundColor = markerColor.value;
```

}

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: repeat(var(--columns-row), 1fr) / repeat(var(--columns-row), 1fr);
    border: solid black 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid div {
    border: 1px dotted lightgrey;
    background-color: var(--bgColor);
 }

 .grid div:hover {
    background-color: var(--color);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that - to both the user and to the system - whether the mouse is up or down is not really related to whether it's in the grid or not.

So, you were seeing the problem on what was an inadvertent drag event, but it was also reproducible if the grid didn't occupy the whole viewport and the 'down' mouse was moved out of the grid and then released while outside the grid. As far as your code was concerned the mouse was still down.

This snippet moves the mouse down/up events to the whole body.

It also checks that the event is related to a square within the grid rather than say just the edge of the grid outside a square.

```js
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
grid.addEventListener('mouseover', colorGrid);

let mousedown = false;

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  mousedown = true;
  colorGrid(event);

});

document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  mousedown = false;
});

function colorGrid(e) {
  if (mousedown && (e.target.parentElement == grid)) e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'pink'; //markerColor.value;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  --columns-row: 8;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(var(--columns-row), 1fr) / repeat(var(--columns-row), 1fr);
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
}

.grid div {
  --bg-color: #ffffff;
  --color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted lightgrey;
  background-color: var(--bgColor);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid div:hover {
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note: I noticed that when I put the mouse down the square underneath didn't change color, I had to move the mouse next door to get that (other) square colored. This snippet colors the square on mousedown. Remove if that's not wanted.